# Kernel Task High CPU and Strange Activity from Other Apps

Tags: macos, cpu, kernel

In Activity Monitor, *kernel_task* is showing that it is using 90% CPU. Chrome can't keep 2 tabs open at the same time without showing "Aw Snap." Other apps are slow and my fan is running at full speed. I have no idea what is causing this. I haven't installed any apps or anything that might affect my Mac.

EDIT: I've also done a SMC reset and a PRAM reset. Still have high CPU usage.

I have listed my Console Log below.

**Console Log**

```
4/09/2016 10:37:21.000 AM kernel[0]: LS(4354) STRANGE TCP connection (dataInBeforeAccept:0) id:3344626 pid:228 conStatus:4 flags:512 original_from:NULL mixedFrom:10.0.0.41:49565 size:b3d mbuf_type:1  data_flags:0
4/09/2016 10:37:21.000 AM kernel[0]: LS(4354) socket: LS_SF_CANT_RECV_MORE pid:0/228 pr:6 flags:536 cState:4 line:1055
4/09/2016 10:37:21.000 AM kernel[0]: LS(4354) STRANGE TCP connection (dataInBeforeAccept:0) id:3344635 pid:228 conStatus:4 flags:512 original_from:NULL mixedFrom:10.0.0.91:44044 size:b3d mbuf_type:1  data_flags:0
4/09/2016 10:37:21.000 AM kernel[0]: LS(4354) socket: LS_SF_CANT_RECV_MORE pid:0/228 pr:6 flags:536 cState:4 line:1055
4/09/2016 10:37:21.000 AM kernel[0]: LS(4354) STRANGE TCP connection (dataInBeforeAccept:0) id:3344669 pid:228 conStatus:4 flags:512 original_from:NULL mixedFrom:10.0.0.41:49568 size:b3d mbuf_type:1  data_flags:0
4/09/2016 10:37:21.000 AM kernel[0]: LS(4354) socket: LS_SF_CANT_RECV_MORE pid:0/228 pr:6 flags:536 cState:4 line:1055
4/09/2016 10:37:22.000 AM kernel[0]: LS(4354) STRANGE TCP connection (dataInBeforeAccept:0) id:3344696 pid:228 conStatus:4 flags:512 original_from:NULL mixedFrom:10.0.0.91:44048 size:b3d mbuf_type:1  data_flags:0
4/09/2016 10:37:22.000 AM kernel[0]: LS(4354) socket: LS_SF_CANT_RECV_MORE pid:0/228 pr:6 flags:536 cState:4 line:1055
4/09/2016 10:37:23.000 AM kernel[0]: LS(4354) STRANGE TCP connection (dataInBeforeAccept:0) id:3344773 pid:228 conStatus:4 flags:512 original_from:NULL mixedFrom:10.0.0.48:33982 size:b3d mbuf_type:1  data_flags:0
4/09/2016 10:37:23.000 AM kernel[0]: LS(4354) socket: LS_SF_CANT_RECV_MORE pid:0/228 pr:6 flags:536 cState:4 line:1055
4/09/2016 10:37:24.000 AM kernel[0]: LS(4354) STRANGE TCP connection (dataInBeforeAccept:0) id:3344803 pid:228 conStatus:4 flags:512 original_from:NULL mixedFrom:10.0.0.48:33984 size:b3d mbuf_type:1  data_flags:0
4/09/2016 10:37:24.000 AM kernel[0]: LS(4354) socket: LS_SF_CANT_RECV_MORE pid:0/228 pr:6 flags:536 cState:4 line:1055
4/09/2016 10:37:24.000 AM kernel[0]: LS(4354) STRANGE TCP connection (dataInBeforeAccept:0) id:3344830 pid:228 conStatus:4 flags:512 original_from:NULL mixedFrom:10.0.0.4:60701 size:b3d mbuf_type:1  data_flags:0
4/09/2016 10:37:24.000 AM kernel[0]: LS(4354) socket: LS_SF_CANT_RECV_MORE pid:0/228 pr:6 flags:536 cState:4 line:1055
4/09/2016 10:37:25.000 AM kernel[0]: LS(4354) STRANGE TCP connection (dataInBeforeAccept:0) id:3344854 pid:228 conStatus:4 flags:512 original_from:NULL mixedFrom:10.0.0.91:44058 size:b3d mbuf_type:1  data_flags:0
```

Comment: What type of Mac is it?

Comment: @IronCraftMan it's a MacBook Air early 2014.

Comment: @Mekul Please add the name of the process with the id 228! And what kind of hosts are 10.0.0.4/41/48/91?

Comment: @klanomath See my answer. Sorry didn't write back sooner. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was an app called [Serviio](http://serviio.org/), which is a kind of Plex alternative.

It uses Java which the process of was 228. This was also the reason that it was trying to connect to IP addresses on my network. I deleted it and it is all back to normal.